# npm request failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.16.35:443

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy, settings, windows-server-2019

We are trying to get npm to work on a Windows Server 2019.

The server is configured like this:

- The server runs as a guest in the ESX VMWare environment.
- Server runs behind a checkpoint firewall and a ClearSwift proxy (several antivirus engines active).
- An F5 load balancing reverse proxy is run internally in the MSM network via DNS.
- Server is running Bitdefender AntiVirus
- Server runs with Windows2019 current patch status.

Current firewall settings:

- All Denied LAN> Intranet
- All Denied Intranet> LAN

We always get this error, no matter what we tried:
[image]

This is what we tried so far:

```
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
ping proxy
npm config set proxy https-proxy http://proxy.johndoe.corp:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.johndoe.corp:8080
npm config set strict-ssl false
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.johndoe.corp:8080
set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.johndoe.corp:8080

npm --proxy  http://proxy.johndoe.corp:8080 --without-ssl --insecure -g install

npm install --global gulp@3.9.1
```

We always get the ETIMEDOUT error, and I wasn't able to find the correct solution on the internet.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: did you make it work?

Comment: @Symlis Yeah the admin had to change some network settings to allow that IP adress

Comment: It turned out they removed proxy so I just had to set it to null